# Closing google chrome extension by itself

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created my first google chrome extension,
All is working great but issue when I am doing any event to browser like scroll down\up its just closing by itself.
any possible reason? 
I dont did any code that supposed to close the windows.
I just using 3 files

popup.html,popup.js,manifest.json

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Popups are closed automatically as soon as the lose focus.

So, if you do anything with the currently open tab, it loses focus and gets destroyed.